# Simultaneously display error on two `EditTexts` in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm working on a from in android. It has a two `EditText`s, one for name and the other for email. I want that when both the fields are blank, the warning should appear on both fields. Not only the "!" mark encircled in red but also the message I type in:

`Name.setError("Customer's Name is Required!");
Email.setError("Customer's Email is Required!");`

Currently it displays the message only on the field which has focus. How to show the message on fields which are not focused?

Comment: show your layout file

Comment: what has it has to do with my layout? don't we set it programatically by checking conditions at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
if (Name.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Name.setError("Customer's Name is Required!");
                }
 if (Email.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Email.setError("Customer's Email is Required!");
                }
```

Comment: it shows the warning sign with the fields but shows the message on only the field which has focus.

Comment: I have never seen this work actually so I don't think that is how it is designed to work

Comment: @Eenvincible I'm using just an EditText

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) on both your EditTexts.

```
Name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                 // This is your current text, see if it is empty, do your logic
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
```

Repeat for the Email `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

try this its working for me

```
if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("") || email.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
               name.setError("Customer's Name is Required!");
                email.setError("Customer's Email is Required!");
            } else {
                // code here
         }
```